# macOs terminal error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, веб-сервер, macos, terminal, scala

Господа, в  терминале хочу запустить сервер(java, scala).

После выполнения команды: "./activator run" - которая должна била запустить сервер, вылетает ошибка с таким тестом: "**[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**"

использую mac и терминал

есть идеи что и почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InvocationTargetException происходит, когда рефлексией запускается метод, и в этом методе происходит какое-либо исключение.
Подозреваю, что сервер пытается рефлексией подтянуть какие-то зависимости или драйверы базы данных - неудачно.
Что можно сделать для решения:

1. Проверьте, что у вас последняя версия Java.
2. Проверьте, что установлены все зависимости, необходимые для работы сервера.
3. Поскольку сервер у вас с [гитхаба](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285450/need-to-start-server-downloaded-from-github), посмотрите в Issues соответствующего репозитория на гитхабе. Возможно, такая проблема уже возникала у кого-то. Если там есть решение - используйте. Если нет - подпишитесь на issue с сообщением о вашей проблеме.
4. Если такой проблемы ни у кого не было - заведите новую запись. Приложите используемую версию сервера, текущую версию JDK, и полностью текст стектрейса. (это то, что идет после)

   > [error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"